# Can fmap be written as a function instead of being called from the library?

Tags: haskell

i'm trying to understand fmap in relation to a function and I was wondering if there was a "simple" way to write out a function that accomplishes the same fmap instead of calling it from the function library?

I'm new to haskell so when I'm checking references, I see a lot of things that my class hasn't gone over yet - and I'm trying to stay ahead of the curve because it's extremely hard and moves quickly.

The library definition of fmap is:

```
 fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

I'm wondering if, with some other function, `fmap` could be written like a helper function to the function implementing `fmap`.

The output would then be exactly as if `fmap` was used but instead we replaced it with a helper function that accomplishes the same task. Is it even possible?

Comment: Think about what the types `a`, `b`, and `f` are.

Comment: `fmap` is a method (in fact the only one) of the `Functor` typeclass. (Your type signature above is missing the `Functor f` constraint.)  As such, it has no "standard" definition, it needs to be defined separately for each `Functor` instance. However, each individual "version" of `fmap` is usually easy to define. For example `fmap` for lists is just `map`, and that has a very simple recursive definition if for some reason you don't want to use library function.

Comment: And since you're only learning, I would say it's not worth worrying about Functors and `fmap` until you are more comfortable with the language, and typeclasses in particular. But certainly familiarise yourself with `map`. And I can thoroughly recommend http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters as a brilliant resource for learning Haskell from scratch.

Comment: `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` is a type, not a definition.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, in fact not the only one. `<$` is the other one.

Comment: @dfeuer good point. I always forget that. (Of course it has a default implementation so I assume it's rare to actually define it.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond, for non-recursive types, it usually doesn't help. For recursive ones, *derived* instances usually do a good job. But hand-written recursive ones usually need help to be optimal. Also, a few types (like `Data.Sequence.Seq`) can pull magic tricks with `<$` performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fmap` is a member of the `Functor` typeclass, defined like so:

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

This means that each type that’s an instance of `Functor` has its own specialised implementation of `fmap`:

```
-- For making type signatures in instances explicit
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}

instance Functor Maybe where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
  fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)
  fmap f Nothing = Nothing

instance Functor [] where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
  fmap f (x : xs) = f x : fmap f xs
  fmap f [] = []
  -- Or: fmap = map
```

When you call `fmap` at a particular type, the compiler automatically selects the appropriate instance to use:

```
-- For making type arguments explicit
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

fmap succ (Just 1)
==
fmap @Maybe succ (Just 1)
==
Just 2

fmap succ [1, 2, 3]
==
fmap @[] succ [1, 2, 3]
==
[2, 3, 4]
```

You could of course use specialised functions directly instead of `fmap`—we would just have separate functions `fmapMaybe`, `fmapList` (`map`), `fmapEither`, `fmapIO`, and so on. However, the advantage of using `fmap`, or typeclasses in general, is that you can write *polymorphic* functions, which work on *any* instance of that typeclass:

```
fmapBoth :: (Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f (a, a) -> f (b, b)
fmapBoth f m = fmap (\ (x, y) -> (f x, f y)) m

fmapBoth succ (Just (1, 2))
==
fmapBoth @Maybe succ (Just (1, 2))
==
Just (2, 3)

fmapBoth succ [(1, 2), (2, 3)]
==
fmapBoth @[] succ [(1, 2), (2, 3)]
==
[(2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Internally, GHC implements this by passing the particular implementation of `fmap` as an extra argument to the function you defined:

```
fmapBoth'
  :: ((a -> b) -> f a -> f b)
  -> (a -> b)
  -> f (a, a)
  -> f (b, b)
fmapBoth' fmapF f m = fmapF (\ (x, y) -> (f x, f y)) m

fmapBoth @[] succ [(1, 2), (2, 3)]
==
fmapBoth' map succ [(1, 2), (2, 3)]
==
map (\ (x, y) -> (succ x, succ y)) [(1, 2), (2, 3)]
==
[(2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

So you can think of a typeclass constraint like `Num a => …` or `Functor f => …` as an additional argument to a function, which happens to be passed implicitly by the compiler, containing a record of all the methods in the particular typeclass. (In fact, the `ImplicitParams` extension lets you use this machinery for implicit arguments of *any* type, although that extension isn’t widely used, since there are generally better alternatives like `Reader`.)

Part of the advantage of using `fmap` instead of specialised functions is that it lets you “code to the interface, not the implementation”—for example, if you’re using lists in your program and later want to change to `Vector` for performance reasons, if you’ve used polymorphic functions like `fmap` everywhere, then you can simply swap out the type and your code will continue to work without modification—but if you’ve used the `map` particular to lists, then you will need to update every call site.

The original purpose of typeclasses was to *avoid* having specialised functions for things like comparisons (`Eq` and `Ord`) and arithmetic (`Num`)—if we didn’t have this polymorphism, then we would need separate functions like `eqInt`, `eqFloat`, `eqChar`, &c. everywhere. Typeclasses let us abstract over this and write `==` regardless of the particular type, and have the compiler insert a call to the appropriate function.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly write specific functions like `mapList :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` and `mapMaybe :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b`.  It sounds as though you haven't learned about type classes yet; you will need them to generalize `mapList` & `mapMaybe` to `fmap`.

You can also read the **source** links in [the docs for `fmap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap)